# Construction of minimal Sullivan model

Tags: homology-cohomology

I have read a lot of papers about constructing a minimal model for a dga $(A,d)$, but still struggle to summarise the minimal data I need to construct the minimal model.
Can someone help!

Also, what information does the minimal model captures that the cohomology doesn't?